# Cocoa search files anywhere

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is there a way I can tag a file on the hard drive, and basically, after the user moves it, the OS keeps track of the file, so when I want to access it again, I just specify the tag and it tells me the location?
I know that I can scan through the entire HD but that would take too long...
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you are not supporting 10.5, but 10.6 and beyond, you might look at NSURL's

```
 - (NSData *)bookmarkDataWithOptions:(NSURLBookmarkCreationOptions)options includingResourceValuesForKeys:(NSArray *)keys relativeToURL:(NSURL *)relativeURL error:(NSError **)error
```

using the `NSURLBookmarkCreationOption` of:

```
NSURLBookmarkCreationPreferFileIDResolution
```

resolves the url using the fileID.